# How to reverse a list without specific elements being reversed in python

Tags: python, reverse

```
f = open (FilePath, "r")

#print f

with open(FilePath, "r") as f:

    lines = f.readlines()
    #print lines


    for iterms in lines:
        new_file = iterms[::-1]
        print new_file
```

it gives me a result like this:
7340.12,8796.4871825,0529.710635,751803.0,fit.69-81-63-40tuo

original list is like this:
out04-32-45-95.tif,0.330693,536043.5237,5281852.0362,20.2260

it is supposed to be like this:
20.2260, ...........out04-32-45-95.tif

Comment: I suspect you want to be splitting your lines (or perhaps using the `csv` module, which will split it for you in a slightly more sophisticated way). Then you can reverse the list of strings before re-joining them with commas, rather than reversing a single string.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using your `for` loop like:

```
for iterms in lines:
    new_file = ','.join(iterms.split(',')[::-1])
    print new_file
```

---

**Explanation:**

In your current code, the line `iterms[::-1]` reverses the entire string present in your line. But you want to only reverse the words separated by `,`.

Hence, you need to follow below steps:

1. **Split the words** based on `,` and get list of words:

   ```
   word_list = iterms.split(',')
   ```
2. **Reverse the words** in the list:

   ```
   reversed_word_list = word_list[::-1]
   ```
3. **Join the reversed wordlist** with `,`

   ```
   new_line = ','.join(reversed_word_list)
   ```